# How is this array is altering its value?

Tags: c++

This is a post from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org about reversing an array.
In the **rvereseArray()** function, array is not using any pointer. But still in the **main()** function, when the **rvereseArray()** function is called and the **arr** is passed, it is able to alter the value. how?

```
// Iterative C++ program to reverse an array
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/* Function to reverse arr[] from start to end*/
void rvereseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}   

/* Utility function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
cout << arr[i] << " ";

cout << endl;
}

/* Driver function to test above functions */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    // To print original array
    printArray(arr, n);
    
    // Function calling
    rvereseArray(arr, 0, n-1);
    
    cout << "Reversed array is" << endl;
    
    // To print the Reversed array
    printArray(arr, n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to read [Why should I _not_ #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/11082165) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165)

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` -> `int n = std::size(arr);` if your compiler is relatively up to date.

Comment: _"array is not using any pointer"_  Short answer: `arr` **is** a pointer in all functions except `main`.